# Bind DropDownList in asp.net in Item Template on row databound

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dropdown

I am trying to bind a dropdown which is in a grid but I am getting error.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdddl" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="grdddl_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcommtype" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("ComPlanRoleDescr") %>'  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcommtype_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnid" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcommtypefooter"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcommtypefooter_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void grdddl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlcommtype = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlcommtype");
            ddlcommtype.DataSource = listcommtype;
            ddlcommtype.DataTextField = "ComPlanRoleDescr";
            ddlcommtype.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlcommtype.DataBind();


        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList ddlcommtype = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlcommtypefooter");
            ddlcommtype.DataSource = listcommtype;
            ddlcommtype.DataTextField = "ComPlanRoleDescr";
            ddlcommtype.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlcommtype.DataBind();
        }
}
```

**This Code is giving error:**
'ddlcommtype' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GridView` you are setting a `SelectedValue` for your `DropDownList`, but 
the value cannot be found in the `ListItem`'s that belong to the DropDownList.

Remove the `SelectedValue` from this line:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcommtype" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("ComPlanRoleDescr") %>'  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcommtype_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

If you do want to use a `SelectedValue`, why not do it after `DataBind()`?  For example:

```
DropDownList ddlcommtype = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlcommtype");
ddlcommtype.DataSource = listcommtype;
ddlcommtype.DataTextField = "ComPlanRoleDescr";
ddlcommtype.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlcommtype.DataBind();

// Now set the default value: 
ddlcommtype.SelectedValue = "InsertValueHere";
```

Comment: but I need to select a value, and it is in the list which binds to the grid.

Comment: This error is for the first time when control doesnt enter in datarow or footer row

Comment: how to give different value for each row as the data for each row is different

Comment: "InsertValueHere" is just a placeholder, you're supposed to change that bit to your variable

Comment: I got your point but I think you didn't got my point. For Each Row there will be different value in the list. How to traverse the list and bind in row data bound

Comment: can you use `ddlcomtype.SelectedValue = ((YourObjectType)e.Row.DataItem).ComPlanRoleDescr;` ?

Comment: What will be myObjectType?

Comment: The class name or type of object you are binding to your initial GridView

Comment: Issue is fixed. I used Linq to select the value for each row